Definition of $E^{\infty}_{p,q}$ in spectral sequence $\{E^r,d^r\}_{r\in\mathbb{Z}}$
Let $\{E^r,d^r\}_{r\in\mathbb{Z}}$ a spectral sequence, that is $E^r$ are differential bigraded $R$-modules $E^r=\bigoplus_{p,q} E^r_{p,q}$ with $d^r$ differential of degree $(-r,r-1)$ (that is $d^r=\bigoplus_{p,q}d^r_{p,q}$ with $d^r_{p,q}:E^r_{p,q} \to E^r_{p-r,q+r-1}$) and $$E^{r+1}_{p,q}\simeq\frac{ker(d^r_{p,q})}{Im(d^r_{p+r,q-r+1})}.$$
This is the definition of $E^{\infty}_{p,q}$ that i know, that is confirmed by this wikipedia link:
suppose we have a sequence $$B_0^{p,q} \subset B_1^{p,q} \subset B_2^{p,q} \subset \cdots \subset B_r^{p,q} \subset \cdots \subset Z_r^{p,q} \subset \cdots \subset Z_2^{p,q} \subset Z_1^{p,q} \subset Z_0^{p,q}$$
such that $E^{r+1}_{p,q}\simeq \frac{Z_i^{p,q}}{B_i^{p,q}}$, then we define $Z_{\infty}^{p,q}:=\cap_iZ_i^{p,q}$ and $B_{\infty}^{p,q}:=\cup_i B_i^{p,q}$ and we define $$E^{\infty}_{p,q}:=\frac{Z_{\infty}^{p,q}}{B_{\infty}^{p,q}}$$
Is this the correct definition? How is this definition well defined? How can be proven that if I have another sequence $\tilde{Z}_i^{p,q}$,$\tilde{B}_i^{p,q}$ satisfying the conditions then $$\frac{\tilde{Z}_{\infty}^{p,q}}{\tilde{B}_{\infty}^{p,q}}=\frac{Z_{\infty}^{p,q}}{B_{\infty}^{p,q}}$$

The definition is correct. You don't just take any sequence, it is a specifically constructed sequence and Wikipedia describes this construction. The point is, roughly speaking, that a subquotient of a subquotient can be canonically expressed as a subquotient again.

Well-definedness issues are not completely absent, though. When reading Weibel - especially to adapt his work to more general Abelian categories - I had to be very, very careful... but it does work out. And to your question here I guess I reiterate what Thorgott said: the $E$ terms are part of the data for a spectral sequence, but in the canonical spectral sequence associated to a filtration we create the $E$ terms from the $Z$, $B$ terms and the $Z,B$ terms are specific and fixed, depending only on the filtration. It is not that we find $Z,B$ such that $E\cong Z/B$; we define $E=Z/B$
